# How to handle packages such as EF, MVC4, WebPages and friends in my project repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-webpages

I have an asp.net application using EF, MVC4 and some additional packages. Whenever I try to open the project on a different PC I have issues with the installed packages. My references are marked as missing, and the code is far from compilable. Last time I solved it by deleting references and packages and installing the needed packages one by one. I find the solution tedious. Is there any better, global solution for this? How is this supposed to be done? Shouldn't this be automated?

Thanks for the help and pointers!

**UPDATE**

I DO use NuGet Packages, (otherwise it would be very hard to get all these dlls) but somehow I always end up with uninstalling and reinstalling the packages to make my project work. I always end up with wrong versions and not compiling code.

I end up doing the following:

- Delete `package.config`
- Delete dependencies from the `web.config` file
- NuGet Package Manager Console:

  - `PM> Uninstall-Package A.B.C`
  - `PM> Install-Package A.B.C`
- Clean - rebuild project and hope for the best

I think Uninstall - Install can be replaced with `Update-Package –reinstall A.B.C`

I was hoping that there is a simpler solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using visual studio; you can enable automatic package restore; this [article](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore) outlines nuget in detail.

If you go to `Tools -> Options -> NuGetPackage Manager` you can make sure that the auto download is enabled.  See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was new for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which references are broken, I would assume that you can at least use NuGet Packages to manage Entity Framework and additional framework references.

Answer (score 0):

As lucian.jp said nuget it probably the way to go. At my company, we usually will go out of our way to find and use only packages that have maintained nuget packages, and even most of the core Microsoft ones have them, for example https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/

For the other ones, keeping a little thirdparty folder with external assemblies/dlls in the root of your repository and then reference from your project to that instead of from some random place on your hard-drive. I.e. check the third party assemblies into your project somewhere that is not your bin directories.

So if you have an existing project, here is what I suggest you do to avoid future issues:

1. For each of the assemblies, including your MVC ones, find the nuget equivalent, remove the dll from your project and add it back using the nuget package manager.
2. Get a copy of all the remaining assemblies and create a folder in the root of your repository and place them in there, then delete all of them and add them back in referencing the dlls from that folder.
3. If you are using git I'd also use .gitignore to not check in your bin directories. Which will force a new deployment of your code to get the assemblies from their respective sources.

Answer (score 0):

Use Nuget for DLL packages like EF and MVC. But do not use Nuget for JS / CSS packages instead go for bower. Nuget packages for CSS and JS libraries are good but just their installation and uninstallation is tricky and may not match your project structure.